# Pagination by Date model for stackoverflow

Tags: feature-request, pagination

The stackoverflow uses numerical pagination. Here is user scenario where the pagination fails:

A user remembers there were two threads from Wednesday (or thereabouts) that he wanted to read but didn't have time to. He wants to quickly find both threads again (and he barely remembers the titles so search does not seem useful).  Today is Sunday.  What page would Wednesday's discussions have fallen on?  Perhaps on Wednesday there were 12 threads, Thursday 5, Friday 7, and Saturday 1.  There is no way for the user to know those volumes and even if he did, he'd have to do an inordinate amount of math in his head to figure out on what page the desired threads appear. I have not yet seen this utilized anywhere and I believe the reason is because I don't think anyone has given this much thought.

To avoid this can we paginate using Date model?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep track of questions, click on the star beneath to the up/down arrows to save it as a [favourite in your profile settings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34642?tab=favorites#sort-top).

Or bookmark the page itself in your browser of choice.

Comment: That's not the OP's point. He want's to filter (paginate) a search based on a time range (e.g. "Monday" or "3 days ago")

Comment: Sounds like trying to fudge up "Newest" sort and not pay attention to the fact that that sort view will show by the days posted. Paginate as you go and you find the relevant days.

Comment: Paginating by days is the 'solution' to a problem that shouldn't exist. You can't expect to find something you don't remember anything about, and inventing systems to try to accommodate this is ridiculous. If you see something you like, remember it's title, or favorite it. If you can't do either of the above, it clearly wasn't important enough and you don't need to find it.