# Pagination fails when changing questions-per-page

Tags: bug, status-completed, pagination

When viewing questions in one of the main tabs, changing the number of questions-per-page preserves the current page number in the URL.  This makes little sense as, for example, the 5th page of 50 items is nowhere near the 5th page of 15 which I was just browsing.

In addition, if I'm viewing 15 per page and I'm at a high enough numbered page (such as the last page of items), when I change pagination to a higher number, I arrive at an empty page well beyond the last page which contains content.

A suggestion such as the one in [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14079/the-navigation-links-for-pagination-of-newest-questions-should-be-relative-to-t) would handily deal with that situation, but at the very least, when changing pagination the page number should probably be simply omitted from the URL.  Jumping back to page one makes at least as much sense as jumping to the same-numbered page at a different pagination.

Comment: I think I know where this one ends up: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6908/increasing-show-x-items-per-page-does-not-working-on-superuser

Comment: Yeah, I'm hoping that the direct approach cuts through the confusion and says simply **the design is broken**.  For which the only response left is `status-doesntmakesense-butnotgonnafixit-pbbth`.  Either that or he can just ignore this bug entirely.

Answer (score 2):

This does not appear to be completed.

Steps to reproduce the bug:
Search for a tag that has a moderate number of questions (>50, <200 would be ideal), like [close-reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/close-reasons).
Set your number of questions per page to be less than 50.
Go to a page number that would exist if the questions were split into groups of 50. For example, [page 4 in a category with 107 questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/close-reasons?page=4&sort=active&pagesize=30).
The [link to set questions-per-page to 50](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/close-reasons?page=4&sort=active&pagesize=50) preserves the page number.
Clicking it takes you to a page devoid of questions.

The tag pages are not particularly bad, but when you search for text inside posts, [the buggy results page you get by following these steps](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?page=3&tab=relevance&pagesize=50&q=leagues) lies and tells you there are no search results, while still giving you links to the existing search results pages at the bottom.

Comment: is it fixed now?

Comment: No, sadly its still broken, I was just about to complain of the same problem