# Pagenation hiccup

Tags: bug, status-completed, pagination

I found a slight hiccup in the pagination mechanism.

Open

```
http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/dhcp
```

I got 88 results and the first page shows 15.

Click on page 6

```
http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=dhcp&page=6&sort=newest&pagesize=15
```

Now click on "50 per page".

```
http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=dhcp&page=6&sort=newest&pagesize=50
```

Because it retains the 'page=6' you get an empty page as there are only two pages when you do 50 per page on 88 results.

Expected behavior: A page that contains at least some of the items from where I came. So in this example I would have expected to see page 2.

Comment: +1 because I'd like it fixed, but it's a dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21627/pagination-fails-when-changing-questions-per-page

Comment: Well, Adam, it's the dupe of a dupe, but: `status-bydesign`

Answer (score 2):

Best solution to fix up these [dupe pagination bugs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug+pagination) is to have the per page setters **not** include the `page=` parameter at all.

Force those who want to switch up between 15, 20, 25, 30, all that money and still riding the bus to go back to the first page of results, but now set with as many of the questions as selected from the bottom right.