# Data Explorer Paging Bug - Changing Per-Page

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

I need to qualify this as not being a dupe of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21627/pagination-fails-when-changing-questions-per-page), well actually it is...but for Data Explorer not SO like the original.

When you change Questions per page, say 100 you land at a URL like this:

> http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?order_by=popular&pagesize=100

The link for the "Page 2" button on that page is this:

> http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?order_by=popular&page=2

It's missing the `pagesize` query parameter currently, seems like it should be:

> http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?order_by=popular&page=2&pagesize=100

Currently it's hopping around in a very unexpected way :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is now fixed](http://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/source/detail?r=322c2a7dafb2cdf55f56ec187215f55cfbb1bd07) and deployed live, now when changing pages [the `pagesize` is kept intact on the generated links](http://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/source/diff?spec=svn322c2a7dafb2cdf55f56ec187215f55cfbb1bd07&r=322c2a7dafb2cdf55f56ec187215f55cfbb1bd07&format=side&path=/App/StackExchange.DataExplorer/Helpers/PageNumber.cs), eliminating the erratic issue described above.  Feel free to change the page size to 30 or 100 now and go nuts.

Comment: It seems it's still (or again) broken, setting the page size to 100 and moving to a different page resets the page size.